# Regular expression to insert a numeric value between filename and extension

Tags: regex, caching, coldfusion

In an article I read if we pass a querystring with JavaScript and CSS files like `style.css?V=1`, in some cases the browser does not cache the files.

So I have decided to write function that will take the file path like `/css/style.css` and will return `/css/style.2342342.css` where 2342342 is the unix timestamp.

```
<cfset mtime = 2342342>
<cfset fileName = "/css/style.css">

<cfset newFileName = REReplace(fileName,'{\\.([^./]+)$}',mtime)>
<cfdump var = "#newFileName#">
```

I got this `'{\\.([^./]+)$}'` regular expression from a Google search but it is not working.

I am not at all good at regular expressions. Please help.

Comment: btw, your caching problems may well be related to the headers being sent with the files - make sure the server is sending appropriate expires/cache-control/last-modified headers.

Comment: @PeterBoughton: Thats why I am appending last modified time stamp with the filename like style.23423324.css, so that the server can reload the file automatically when it will be changed.

Comment: Changing the filename doesn't remove the need to set appropriate HTTP headers.

Comment: You didn't say how you were getting your unix timestamp, but gettickcount() might be simpler.

Comment: @DanBracuk: `<cfset  lstModified = getfileInfo("E:/Workspace3/jquerySliderApp/css/myStyle.css" ).lastmodified > 
<cfset  mtime =  dateDiff("s", "January 1 1970 00:00", lstModified)>`

Comment: What that means is that as long as the file is not updated you are always sending the same number.  If that's your intent, what's the point of sending a number?

Comment: My client wants to set up auto versioning mechanism for the site. I am following this article http://www.particletree.com/notebook/automatically-version-your-css-and-javascript-files/

Comment: @DanBracuk: Let me know is there any other good way to maintain autoversioning.I am appending the timestamp between the filename and extension because sometimes browser do not cache the css/js files with querysting like "v=2.1" in it.

Comment: Dumb question...but are you actually renaming the files with this new file name? If not, your browser will not be able to find them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're over-complicating things by using a regex.  As [jwz](http://www.jwz.org/) said

> "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems."

With Coldfusion, you can simply treat your filename as a list with a `.` for a delimiter.  You want to insert your `mtime` value before the last part of that list.  Assuming your filename doesn't include more than one `.` you could use:

```
<cfset newFileName = listFirst(fileName, '.') & '.' & mtime & '.' & listLast(filename, '.')>
```

Comment: +1 for nice solution and good quote... btw are you aware that the [quote seems to be incomplete](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-humor.html#twoprobs)?  :)

Comment: Downvote for perpetuating that stupid quote/myth, and also because this relies on files containing a single `.` character.

Comment: Agree with Peter, sorry Dunc. Also this: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2014/05/regarding-regex-two-things-id-like.html

Comment: I love regex, but probably not the best solution for this problem. I made a small adjustment to the solution so that it will work for any file name (just a different syntax from Peter's, I think).

Comment: your suggestion was rejected by committee it seems... maybe post it as your own answer :-)

Comment: It's equivalent (but more long-winded) syntax to what Scott posted, but _different behaviour_ to what I posted. My non-regex solution was specifically done to work backwards from the end of the string. Using ListInsertAt/ListDeleteAt/ListLen all require starting at the beginning.

Comment: Oh and regex is a good solution here because it's concise and easy to update if the requirements change.

Answer (score 5):

The `{\\.([^./]+)$}` you found is not a functioning regex - in so far as `{` and `}` are not used like that in regex. It's possible some language uses those as delimiters for a regex, but in actual regex they are used for quantifiers, (for example `x{3,5}` matches between 5 and 3 of x).

Also, with `\\.` that is looking for a literal `\` followed by `.` as a metacharacter (which is not the intent - it should just be `\.`). (Again this may be due to whatever language that example came from requiring backslashes to be escaped; CF doesn't require it, and thus doing so interferes with the regex behaviour.)

### Regex solution:

```
rereplace( filename , '(?=\.[^./]+$)' , '.' & mtime )
```

This uses a lookahead `(?=..)` instead of a capturing group to simplify the replacement side - the replacement is inserted at the *position* before the final `.` without replacing any actual characters.

If it ever comes to replacing the timestamp, it's easy to add `\.\d+` to the start and have it just work.

### Non-regex solution:

```
Left(filename,filename.lastIndexOf('.')+1) & mtime & '.' & ListLast(filename,'.')
```

Potentially more efficient (but not necessarily to a significant level).

One of the downsides of regex is that they're one-way - they start at the beginning and go forward. For long strings when you only care about the last few characters that can mean wasting time looking at characters you don't care about. Methods like `lastIndexOf` and `ListLast` work backwards from the end, and thus avoid those unnecessary inspections. Again, in this situations the strings are short enough it almost certainly wont matter, but it is something worth keeping in mind.

Comment: Nice regex, Peter! Never thought of using a look-ahead in a replacement like that.

Comment: Yeah, it can be handy to remember regex works with positions - I use it a fair bit on the IDE side (e.g. refactoring across files), though annoyingly it doesn't work in Eclipse and I have to switch to jEdit.  _(side-note: I'm not ignoring that McName article you did, just haven't had enough spare time to respond yet - hopefully this weekend.)_

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list-based solution that may be a bit simpler - and, addresses the point Peter mentions about more than one `.` in a file name.

```
<cfset mtime = 2342342>
<cfset fileName = "/css/style.css">
<cfset newFileName = listInsertAt( fileName, listLen( filename, '.'), mtime, '.' ) />
```

You would likely need to add more logic to check that `listLen( filename, '.')` is at least 2, but this is a start.